# ASP.NET directory references

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

I'm learning ASP.NET for web applications as I go along, so this may be a stupid question.

Suppose I make a reference to a file in the code like this:

```
private string LogText()
{
    return System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:/logs/log.txt");
}
```

Will that directory be interpreted as server-side or client-side? Meaning, if a user accesses the web form and invokes that method, would the file be read from that directory on their PC or the directory on the server hosting the form? I'm really hoping it's the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will interperted as server side and not as client side. This piece of code is being executed in the server, hence this gone be interpreted in the server side. Hence, this file will be read from the serve's corresponding directory and not of the client's corresponding directory.